# colored dots on matlab plot

Tags: matlab, plot, pca, scatter

I want to make a PCA-plot, where the colour of each dot is given by a special number. The colour of the dot should be from blue (small number) to red (large number). I am trying to do this:

```
 scatter(pc(1,:),pc(2,:),15,c,'filled')
```

c - is a 1x40 array, where the numbers for each dot are written. I get only differently coloured dots, but not from blue to red.
Could someone help me please?

Comment: What exactly is in `c` ? Is that a `40x3` array you set up yourself? What about using `c = jet(40)` for the colors?

Comment: you can type `colormap(jet(40))` after your scatter instruction, but @Benoit_11 solution should work too.

Comment: Oh I see it's a `1x40` array actually...well what's in it?

Answer (score 2):

Your ***c*** argument is a vector if it is 1x40. According to the help for the SCATTER function:

> *When C is a vector the same length as X and Y, the values in C are linearly mapped to the colors in the current colormap.*

This means that the colors you see are dependent on your colormap.

If you need each marker to be a specific color, you can take advantage of this behavior:

> *When C is a length(X)-by-3 matrix, it directly specifies the colors of the  markers as RGB values.*